# Checking for proper administrative location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, vector, geolocation

I have two vector layers. The first layer contains points. This layer has a lot of fields with data like name of district, [voivodeship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voivodeship) etc.

The second layer (polygon) is showing administrative division (commune, district, [voivodeship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voivodeship)).

Based on the second layer (polygon) I have to check that names in table (first layer - points) like "commune, district , [voivodeship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voivodeship)" are correct.

Is there any solution?

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE, you need to alter your question to include exactly what software you are using to display your layers, possibly some code snippets of how you have your layers set up will also help you get a meaningful answer. If you are doing this in a database, you need to include information about that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Andrew-OpenGeoCode mentions- arcpy would provide a programmatic solution.
An alternative to a script might be the [intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000) tool.

You should be able to intersect the points and polygons to create a new feature  which contains attributes for both features.
You could then create 3 new columns and use the [field calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_field_calculations/005s00000025000000/) to compare the attributes to check if they are the same - which would probably involve some pre-logic to compare the fields.
Something similar to this codeblock:

[image: example field calculation]

where in 'compare(!nm!,!nm_1!)' - nm is the district column of your points, and nm_1 would be the district column of your polygon attributes.

Comment: yes, of course, i forgot

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two sets of data. A first set (points) appears to be points-of-interest (POIs) with geographic level information (e.g., 1st admin div, 2nd admin div, populated place, etc). The second set (polygon) are the outline shapes (area) of the administrative divisions.

If so, I would do the following:

A. Iterate through the set of points.
B. For point, obtain the admin division assigned to the point.
C. Find the polygon for the corresponding admin div.
D. Test if the point is within the ploygon.
E. If yes, the data for the point is good.
F. If not, iterate through the remainin polygons and test which polygon the point is within.
G. Once found, correct the data for the point with the actual admin division it is within.

Answer (score 0):

I`m using ArcGis 10.2," to Andrew" , in which layer i should write vba statement/phyton? Could you show me an example? Now i`m checking admin div by admin div with select by location, it`s a lot of work...i would like to automize this work. Before, i tried transform my second layer to raster and then i used zonal statistic tool. The result of this procedure was raster with field value with number corrensponding admin div.